# How do I lane safely on Twisted Treeline?

Tags: league-of-legends

With the remade Twisted Treeline map, laning can be very tricky as they are very vulnerable to ganks, especially due to there being no wards allowed on the map any more.

Are there any techniques I can use to lane as safely as possible, without falling behind my opponent's experience and gold?

Comment: I'd answer WARDS but I'm afraid I'll be downvoted...
Being mainly a twisted treeline player I can't wait to try the new version of the map. I'm still waiting for my new Internet connection to happen and it's painful not being able to test all these changes...

So back to your question my suggestion to anyone asking a How Can I Be Safe from Ganks question is if you feel that a certain team is in the mood for ganks ward a lot and dont be afraid to overextend. This way you will make them think they can gank you and they  will get baited into losing exp by leaving their lane.

Comment: @Panagiotis Palladinos the new map is really nice man. One thing though, you cannot buy wards any more, this is the main reason I ask this question!

Comment: damn that sounds intriguing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communication with teammates is key.

If your opponent disappears with 10% health, let your teammates know he (probably) recalled. If your opponent disappears with 100% health, warn your teammates of the possible gank.

Of course, depending on your champ, you might have additional resources available to you. Teemo, for example, can be more certain than most of his safety in lane.

Comment: Very general. It can be used in Twisted Treeline and in Summoners Rift.

Comment: But more pressing on TT, in that the time-of-travel between the lanes is much lower, and the absence of wards makes it (barring champs who can leverage pseudo-wards, like Teemo or Maokai) the sole focus for lane safety.

Comment: The most successful strategy that I have seen in the new TT map is two solo-lanes with a single jungle/support, but communication with the jungler is key.

Answer (score 0):

Travel distance between lanes are very very short. So if you're laning top lane (assuming it's double bot), then the best way to keep up in exp and prevent ganks is [from my experience] run a fast pusher in top lane.

```
Push quickly
    farm Jungle
    gank bot
```

And if anyone's missing, your teammates or you yourself should be able to countergank if you see it coming. If enemy freezes lane, you could either gank bot or have one of your teammates gank top solely for the pressure, and force push it to the tower, thus resetting the lane.

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Note on the double single lane and 1 jungler. Top 3v3 team runs double lane and single lane top. Their idea is this: Crush one lane, dominate map. if you win the lane with 2 people, you'll have two useful people that can help carry the burden top has if top's shaky.